# What does Pending Change: "edit , [more]" mean?

Tags: version-control, tfs, azure-devops

I'm new to TFS and have spent ages Googling and browsing Microsoft's TFS documentation.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is checked out by more than one user.

Comment: Edit means that the file has been checked out for edit by user(s) in their  local workspace.

Comment: We don't have any local workspaces, our TFS version is too old.